# What Sets the Actual End Date for an Email?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

What populates the Actual End date field for a CRM 2011 Email record?

Below are actual Email record fields from a CRM 2011 database:

```
Created On          | Modified On         | Actual End
2012-11-15 19:46:00 | 2012-11-15 19:46:01 | 2012-11-15 22:46:57
2012-11-15 18:31:04 | 2012-11-15 18:31:04 | 2012-11-15 22:46:57
2012-11-15 16:47:48 | 2012-11-15 16:47:48 | 2012-11-15 22:29:22
```

The issue is that the Actual End dates are immediately set to several hours in the future PLUS a seemingly random number of minutes. I would understand if it was a difference of hours due to +/- GMT but there's no basis that I can see. Also note that the top two emails were sent at different times but the Actual End is exactly the same. In the case of the top two records a user sent one and then I sent the other a little over 1 hour later.

Note that there aren't any workflows modifying these emails or any other jobs. I also confirmed that both Outlook clients had their local time set correctly and that the time on the server is also correct. Clearly something populates that field but it's not clear what that is or how it's calculates that time nor why it's different from the other date fields.

Server is rollup 8, Outlook rollup 11.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how this works?

Answer (score 3):

the actualend attribute of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM E-mail entity is populated with the value of the ReceivedOn date from the e-mail messages.

Also, note that the time-zones on the actualend attribute can be wrong due to a bug. however it was fixed in [one of these hotfixs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949256)